# How to use RandomForest to predict a result after n days?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree, prediction

How to use the Random Forest Classifier to predict? but not classified a testing data?

For example, I have a data set like

1. [Date,Temp,Humid,Change]
2. [2018-04-05, 30, 75%,nan]
3. [2018-04-06, 30, 90%,0]
4. [2018-04-07, 31, 80%,1]
5. [2018-04-08, 32, 50%,1]
6. [2018-04-09, 29, 80%,-1]

"Change" is the target to be predict. And I want to predict all the "Change" value in the next 10 days. How can I do it? I am using Python. Thanks!!

Comment: How many observation datapoints do you have for this 1E+3, 1E+4, 1E+5?

Comment: @user3666197 sorry, I am not quite understand your question with "observation datapoints". But I have a csv file with 26 features, and one target.

Comment: Never mind, **how many rows of `[Date, Temp, Humid, Change ]` data**  do you have ready to use?

Comment: around 10 rows of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You will not use the `RandomForestClassifier()` ensemble of models,

but the **`.RandomForestRegressor()`** instead.

---

### The principal workflow goes like this:

you will instantiate the supervised learning "empty" ensemble-model for regression:

```
   aRfREGRESSOR = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor( <_Learner_PARAMETERs_> )
```

### Next,

you will prepare training data:

```
 X = transform_input_data_into_X_features_( <_input_data_on_MEASUREMENTs_> )
 y = transform_input_data_into_Y_GND_TRUTH( <_input_data_on_CHANGE_on_10thDAY_after> )
```

### Next,

you will train the model, using a supervised training method, providing both the **`X`** ( observations ) and **`y`** ( respective prediction targets ):

```
 aRfREGRESSOR.fit( X, y )
```

### Next,

the ensemble-model will be now be ready to make predictions:

```
aRfREGRESSOR.predict( transform_input_data_into_X_features(  <_a_MEASUREMENT_> ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can I change it as an classification problem? For an example, I want to classifiy the next 5 days temperture as increase or decrease from the dataset, but not the exact value of the temperture. Can I do it?

Comment: Why not, create also another model for each such task. If training an Up_or_Down_Temperature_after_5_Days_from_Now-predictor, may enjoy an ensemble-based classifier to learn that as best as possible from known data ( using a supervised learning process ).

Comment: I have built a model of RF classifier, but I got a result with 100% accuracy and OOB error...How can I fix it?